# Is it possible to tow a smaller aircraft (like a LSA with a non-functioning engine) with a more powerful towplane?

Tags: towing

The idea is to move an otherwise flyable aircraft with a bad engine from an airstrip with no facilities, to an FBO with a AP mechanic available for an engine swap. Let's say perhaps 100-200 miles, VFR conditions, takeoff, climb to cruise altitude, descent, and landing.

Comment: Although there are tow planes made to do this, would it be practical to tow an LSA not made specifically to be towed? Where would you attach the tow rope? How would you disconnect it in an emergency?

Comment: I don't know if you're in the US but if you are, and if "possible" includes "legal", then you'd need an FAA waiver per 91.311.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

I know of a pilot in the USA who has done exactly this.  Both aircraft were Cessna 182s.  The aircraft to be towed was outfitted with a releasable tow hook mounted on the prop shaft (I believe the prop was removed).  It took a lot of effort to satisfy the FAA that this could be done safely.  Part of this effort included videotaping towing a Cessna 182 (the one that ended up being the towplane) into the air via the same prop shaft-mounted towhook with a motorcycle on a long 7000' runway.  Since the motorcycle had much less engine power than a Cessna 182, this was evidence that the concept would work.

The end result was that the disabled plane was successfully ferried in this manner, with permission from the FAA.  I don't recall the exact starting point of the ferry flight but I believe the distance was in the neighborhood of 60 miles.

The ending point was an untowered field and as best as I recall the starting point was as well.

Naturally, the tow line was released before the aircraft entered the landing pattern.

This all happened sometime between 1990 and 2005; I don't recall the date more accurately than that.

If your LSA did not have a tractor (nose-mounted) engine, you might have more of a challenge.

A qualified glider tow pilot will be needed to fly the towplane.

Comment: As an addition. You will need a qualified glider tow pilot. Ferry flights must specify the route and avoid populated areas. There are requirements for glider tow lines and connections.

Comment: Did the motorcycle stay on the ground during the test?

Comment: @Someone-OnStrike --yes, naturally.  I don't recall how long the tow line was in that test or how high the airplane climbed -- probably just high enough to demonstrate that it was clearly out of ground effect and able to maintain altitude.  A full-blown auto-tow style glider launch using only a motorcycle obviously might be dangerous to the motorcycle driver.

Answer (score 2):

Of course it is possible, but I think your main challenge will be twofold:

1. Rigging the LSA legally with a glider tow point that can be released if necessary.  If it wasn't designed to be towed whatever you come up with will need to be inspected and approved for flight.
2. Performing an intentional power-off "emergency" landing at the other end.  Without a functional engine the LSA is not airworthy, so I doubt any controlled airfield would allow you to land it there.

Not to mention how are you planning to calculate fuel needed?  Your tow aircraft performance charts won't account for the extra drag, and you aren't talking about a short trip...

I would suggest it might be easier to just go pick up the A&P and bring him back to do the swap.

Comment: ...or put your LSA on a trailer and drive it there.

Comment: Re #2, if you drop the tow line, you are now in an airplane with a non-working engine, so you declare an emergency :-)  Plus LOTS of airports don't have control towers or anything, so you just listen to the Unicom (if there is one), watch for traffic, and land.

Comment: @jamesqf, right, essentially creating an emergency situation on purpose.  It would be pretty tough to explain your decision making process to the NTSB if you mess up and land short.  In my mind I'm already drafting the "Darwin Award" writeup...

Comment: You'd attach the tow rope to a bridle around the towed airplane's spinner, but, as others have noted, the risks involved are far greater than bringing the A&P and the replacement engine to that airplane.

Comment: If the airport is untowered, the landing should be no issue. It's no different than if you were landing a glider there. No need to declare an emergency. No need to consider the pilot for a Darwin Award. Obviously you are going to go to an airport with little traffic, or you are going to announce on the radio what is going on and make sure there is a break in the traffic.  Even if the field were towered, it would be no different than landing a glider there.

Comment: @quiet flyer, except that it isn't a glider, it is an aircraft with a non functioning engine that is designed to be flown with power.  Of course unpowered forced landings can be done safely, but they are considered an emergency.  A couple standard principles of risk management is to accept no uneccessary risk, and accept risk only when outweighed by benefits.  I don't think creating an intentional emergency situation is the wisest course of action in this case, but if the OP is willing to bet his pilot cert on his ability to explain his decision making process to the FAA, then go for it...

Comment: " but they are considered an emergency."-- why, when you release the towrope at a time of your choosing and a location of your choosing?  I don't think the pilot involved considered it an emergency.  You could ask, "why should anyone ever fly a glider at all, since it creates an unnecessary risk?"

Comment: Read my comment again, I’m not talking about gliders.  When an engine quits on a single engine powered plane it is an emergency.

Comment: But the engine didn't quit in flight, if it was inoperative before takeoff.

Comment: Many's the light plane that's been converted into a glider by removing the engine -- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JTGJcNo2LU0&feature=youtube&t=136 ( intentionally starts at t=136), https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LC-QIEzorFI

Comment: “But the engine didn't quit in flight, if it was inoperative before takeoff.” The timeline of when the engine quit isn’t the issue here, it is the fact that you are airborne in a non-airworthy aircraft that makes it an emergency. The fact that you did it intentionally actually reinforces my point, and is what brings your judgement into question. But if you think you could walk the FAA through your rationale and convince them that this is a better option than fixing it in place then detail out the reasons in your own answer. I think it is a bad idea, & I’m not going to argue opinions with you.

Comment: P.S.  Engineered removal of the engine from a few cubs during war time by the military, sanctioned by the CAA for glider training, is pretty far removed from what this guy is planning.  In fact it ties directly into the principle of accepting risk when there is a benefit.  And it doesn’t exactly bolster your claim that “many have been converted”...